# Power Query Multiply Many Columns by one Fixed Column

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I'm a noob and need help with a Power Query project. I have a merged query from two different tables: first table contains a bill of materials including `Item Number` and `Usage Quantity`; second table contains a weekly sales plan. I want to multiply all of the weekly sales columns by the `Usage Quantity`.

My attempt at a solution was:

`= Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {}, each _ * {"Usage Quantity"})`

What I believe is happening is all of the columns, including Item Number and Usage Quantity, are being multiplied by Usage Quantity and it is resulting in errors.

| Item Number | Usage Quantity | 10/16/2023 | 10/23/2023 | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 1 | 10 | 20 |  |
| XYZ456 | 0.5 | 5 | 7 |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to multiply all fields by the Usage Quantity column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Names  = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Source"),2), // skip first two columns from the transform
Transform = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(Source, (x)=>Record.TransformFields(x, List.Transform( Names, (y) => { y, each _ * x[Usage Quantity] } ) ) ))
in Transform
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Unpivot `sales` table before joining with material table
- Merge two table and add a column ([Value]*[Usage Quantity])
- Pivot `date` column

Table: materials

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="materials"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item Number", type text}, {"Usage Quantity", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Table: sales

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="sales"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item Number", type text}, {"10/16/2023", Int64.Type}, {"10/23/2023", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Item Number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "Date"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Table: MergeTable

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(sales, {"Item Number"}, materials, {"Item Number"}, "materials", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded materials" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "materials", {"Usage Quantity"}, {"Usage Quantity"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded materials", "NewValue", each [Value]*[Usage Quantity]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Date]), "Date", "NewValue", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

---

Three PQ formulas could be merged if you prefer to have less query.

```
let
    materials = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="materials"]}[Content],
    salesSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="sales"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(salesSource, {"Item Number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    sales = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "Date"}}),
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(sales, {"Item Number"}, materials, {"Item Number"}, "materials", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded materials" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "materials", {"Usage Quantity"}, {"Usage Quantity"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded materials", "NewValue", each [Value]*[Usage Quantity]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Date]), "Date", "NewValue", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I did this on PQ for Mac, which has its inherent issues. That said, see if this solves your problem:

1. First, unpivot item number and usage quantity. This will produce something like this:

```
    +-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
    | item number | usage qty | Attribute | Value |
    +-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
    | a           |         1 | date 1    |    10 |
    | a           |         1 | date 2    |    20 |
    | b           |       0.5 | date 1    |     5 |
    | b           |       0.5 | date 2    |     7 |
    +-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

2. The next step is to add a custom column, which merely multiplies the usage quantity by the column Value.
3. You then remove both of those columns in the next step.
4. Last but not least, pivot the Attribute column and make sure the Value column is set to your custom column. This is the result:

```
    +-------------+--------+--------+
    | part number | date 1 | date 2 |
    +-------------+--------+--------+
    | a           |     10 |     20 |
    | b           |    2.5 |    3.5 |
    +-------------+--------+--------+
```

Obviously, change column headings etc. to fit your requirements.